# Unable to locate command :: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Windows Phone 7 app development with cordova 2.3.0. I get the error 'Unable to locate command :: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' on FB.login. I started off with the code base that works fine in Android. What am I missing or not doing right on Windows? Any detailed documentation about PhoneGap WP7 and Facebook plugin integration?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the namespace in call method:

look my example:

Cordova.exec(null, null, "WP7GapClassLib.PhoneGap.Commands.MyCommand", "SendRequest", args);

Comment: Same conversation on [google goups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/ie4Py8jiA7I/rhyXW4p5MOoJ) with one more response. Looks like this did not help the OP. Did not work for [me either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877587/phonegap-3-3-0-unable-to-locate-command-localnotification). Gives me `Plugin not allowed in config.xml`.