# Phonegap 3.3.0: Unable to locate command :: LocalNotification

Tags: javascript, plugins, cordova, windows-phone-8

**Background**: I add the Windows Phone 8 Version of [Katzer's LocalNotifications Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) into [asiFarran's LocalNotifications Plugin](https://github.com/asiFarran/Phonegap-Plugins-LocalNotifications). After I changed `config_munge` in `plugins/wp8.json` from ' :0' to `:1` I am not getting `Plugin not allowed in config.xml` anymore and log shows `Adding feature.value=LocalNotification` but now:

**Question**: Log shows `Unable to locate command :: LocalNotification`.

I tracked this down to [CommandFactory.cs line 94](https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp8/blob/3.3.x/wp8/template/cordovalib/CommandFactory.cs#L94).

My `plugin.xml` contains for wp8:

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="LocalNotification">
            <param name="wp-package" value="LocalNotification"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/wp8/LocalNotification.cs" />
    <source-file src="src/wp8/Options.cs" />
</platform>
```

And plugin is added in `config.xml`:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.stratogos.cordova.localNotifications" version="0.1.0" />
```

Files get copied into `platform/wp8`. I removed and recreated the wp8 platform but that did not fix it.

If I [set the namespace in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743345/unable-to-locate-command-org-apache-cordova-facebook-connect) method I am back to: `Plugin not allowed in config.xml`.

In JavaScript I am calling

```
exec(null,null,"LocalNotification","addNotification",[defaults]);
```

The plugin has `src/wp8/LocalNotification.cs` with:

```
namespace Cordova.Extension.Commands
{
    public class LocalNotification : BaseCommand
    {
        public void addNotification(string jsonArgs)
        {
...
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_wp8_plugin.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Plugins) the Class name must match with what I am calling in `exec()`. So my mistake must be somewhere else I think.

**Update**

I could not find the `LocalNotification.cs` in the wp8 project. How and where is this plugin file supposed to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by manually adding the wp8 source files from `plugins/YOURPLUGIN/src/wp8/*` into the project. If you open it in Visual Studio you can drag and drop the file into a folder. I dragged it into `/cordovalib` but an extra folder for plugins would be nicer.